# How do I observe property changes in Polymer 3?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

How do I implement continuous checking (time based) of a property-change in a component using an event listener in Polymer 3?

These are my [component's](https://github.com/sakisondhi/test/blob/master/map-comp.js) properties:

```js
static get properties() {
  return {
    longitude: {
      type: Number
    },
    latitude: {
      type: Number
    },
    accuracy: {
      type: Number
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: static get properties() {

    return {
      longitude: {
        type: Number
      },
      latitude: {
        type: Number
      },
      accuracy: {
        type: Number
      }
    };

  }            In this function I want to know how to check for change in longitude and latitude values( that r being passed from html code while running the component) dynamically and update the same accordingly using polymer 3.

Comment: Please do not add code to a comment, rather edit the question. And the given code does only return static stuff from my point of view. Where should a change be detected?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [complex observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/observers#multi-property-observers) that is called whenever any of the specified properties change. To do this, declare an `observers` getter that returns a string array, where each string is the observer method name, followed by a list of dependencies (i.e., properties to be observed) in parentheses:

```
static get observers() {
  return ['_onPropsChanged(longitude, latitude, accuracy)'];
}

_onPropsChanged(longitude, latitude, accuracy) {
  console.log({ longitude, latitude, accuracy });
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-3-observers?file=index.js)